# Upload a large TTL file to virtuoso graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, spring-webclient, virtuoso, large-file-upload

I am trying to write a ttl file to a graph in virtuoso using HTTP post call to the graph endpoint,

```
resource = new ClassPathResource("beil0.ttl").getFile();
        String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));
        WebClient webClient = webConfig.webClientBuilder().build();
        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = webClient.post()
                .uri("?graph-uri=http://data.else.com/voca/comp/")
                .header("Content-Type", "text/turtle")
                .bodyValue(text)
                .retrieve();
        String responseBody = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Here i am reading the file first in variable 'text' and then passing it to the post call which eventually gives me an error as follows :-

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: writerIndex(0) + minWritableBytes(-1932256561) exceeds maxCapacity(2147483647): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 2147483647)
```

I am assuming its a big file so this error is being thrown from the virtuoso endpoint, if my assumption is right then what i want to do is stream this file content to the endpoint rather than sending it all together.
Does anyone has an idea how can i achieve such functionality here.
FYI - I tried to use INPUTSTREAM, MULTIPART and many other ways that i can find online but i am still not able to achieve it because of one reason or another.

Comment: The error is a java error from the local JVM. Seems like the file is over 2Gbytes (2147483647 = 2^31 − 1). That exceeds a java int.

Comment: The file i am trying to upload is actually around 800MB in size, converting it to string and then passing it to POST call is definitely not a good option thats why i am trying to search a method where i can pass it as a Input Stream

Comment: InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream("filePath"));
WebClient webClient = webConfig.webClientBuilder().build();
HttpStatus responseSpec = webClient.post()
.uri("?graph-uri=http://data.com/voca/c/")
.header("Content-Type", "text/turtle")
.body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
.exchangeToMono(response -> {
if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
return response.bodyToMono(HttpStatus.class).thenReturn(response.statusCode());
} else {throw new IllegalStateException("Error uploading file");}}).block();

Comment: Currently this is what i am trying right now but it throws an error as follows :-
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use these Virtuoso samples for loading RDF data to Virtuoso via TCP connection. (The samples are in Gradle project format.)

1. [RDFLoader via Jena API](https://github.com/OpenLinkSoftware/Virtuoso_Java_Samples/tree/main/Jena/RDFLoader) uses the [Virtuoso Jena Provider](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider)
2. [RDFLoader via RDF4J API](https://github.com/OpenLinkSoftware/Virtuoso_Java_Samples/tree/main/RDF4J/RDFLoader) uses the [Virtuoso RDF4J Provider](https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSesame2Provider)